# ECC DDR5: EC8 (80-bit) vs EC4 (72-bit) data integrity capabilities?

Tags: memory, hardware, ecc

I have been looking info about ECC on DDR5 DIMMs (full ECC, non on-die ECC) and I have seen that there are two different types:

1. EC4, which uses 4 ECC bits per subchannel, for a total of 72 bits width
2. EC8, which uses 8 ECC bits per subchannel, for a total of 80 bits width

One difference is that EC4 seems to be used for UDIMMs and EC8 for RDIMMs, but what I really want to know and I can't find it's the difference on data integrity between both of them. It's EC4 considered "full" ECC and SECDED?

DDR4 uses only an EC8 model with a total of 72 bits, is this equivalent to DDR5 EC4 72-bits or to EC8 80-bits when we talk about data integrity and error correction?